# There's one line of Reddit's code (the ranking feature) made me confused

Tags: python, reddit

The code is from this page:
https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/db/_sorts.pyx

Here is the code snippet:

```
cpdef double epoch_seconds(date):
"""Returns the number of seconds from the epoch to date. Should
   match the number returned by the equivalent function in
   postgres."""
td = date - epoch
return td.days * 86400 + td.seconds + (float(td.microseconds) / 1000000)
```

I think `td.days * 86400` should be equal to `td.seconds` as well as `(float(td.microseconds) / 1000000)`, I was wondering why didn't they simply make td.seconds multiply 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your assumptions are wrong and that is why this seams weird. `td.days` contains the number of days since the epoch as you correctly assumed, but `td.seconds` and `td.microseconds` contains the number of seconds since the start of the day and the number of microseconds since the start of the second respectively. Thus the return value becomes the number of seconds since the epoch with microseconds as the part after the comma.

Answer (score 2):

`td.days` is the integer number of days, with any fraction of a day truncated.  Likewise, `td.seconds` is the integer number of seconds within that "fraction of a day", with any fraction of a second truncated.  So you have to piece together the components.